# How can I partially reload content on a web page?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, nginx

I am currently working on the development of a platform and I was wondering how sites like Behance, Artsation and upwork do to partially reload their page. (When you click on a link, the page loads well but the menu does not move just like the footer). I first thought of Nginx but Artsation does not seem to be used Nginx.
I would like to know the things to reproduce this kind of loading page if someone could enlighten me on the subject.

EDIT: I already know ajax, but the thing is that on behance, the server seems to really redirect

Thanks

Comment: They use AJAX to reload data. It has nothing to do with the web server itself.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough or I went a bit in the air asking the question, I'm sorry.
I already use Vuejs for my project (all front end, router, store, I use axios to recover data from my API), but I'm looking for a way to relieve JS files that weigh more than 2 MB. That's why Behance interest me, it seems to give this impression of redirection without redirection, I would rather say that it is this effect that I would like to reproduce.
Next time I will try to ask questions more clearly :)
Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You probably should learn about AJAX, here is a starting place:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

And if you use jquery

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: I already know ajax, but the thing is that on behance, the server seems to really redirect

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Behance uses Ngnix.
Second, If you want to create a real-time web application you need to do it with NodeJS and Express or any framework based on NodeJS. But there is an alternative, which is Ajax.

So using ajax will helps you to load contents on your website in each couple of seconds or load a part of your page.

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytKc0QsVRY4

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough or I went a bit in the air asking the question, I'm sorry.
I already use Vuejs for my project (all front end, router, store, I use axios to recover data from my API), but I'm looking for a way to relieve JS files that weigh more than 2 MB. That's why Behance interest me, it seems to give this impression of redirection without redirection, I would rather say that it is this effect that I would like to reproduce.
Next time I will try to ask questions more clearly :)
Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was not clear enough or I went a bit in the air asking the question, I'm sorry.
I already use Vuejs for my project (all front end, router, store, I use axios to recover data from my API), but I'm looking for a way to relieve JS files that weigh more than 2 MB. That's why Behance interest me, it seems to give this impression of redirection without redirection, I would rather say that it is this effect that I would like to reproduce.
Next time I will try to ask questions more clearly :)
Sorry for the inconvenience